# FFMPEG is not found Discord.js

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server, discord

I'm using Ubuntu Linux (64-bit) with Node.js and npm installed.
In my project file, I have run the following commands:

```
$ sudo npm install discord.js node-opus --save
$ sudo npm install discord.js-arbitrary-ffmpeg --save
$ sudo npm install ffmpeg --save
$ sudo npm install forever -g
$ sudo npm install forever-monitor
```

After doing so, I added an *eval* function which allows only me to run whatever commands I want. The following code is:

```
if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('^eval'){
  try{
    eval(message.content.substring(5));
  }catch(e){
    message.author.send(e);
  }
  return;
}
```

Then, in Discord, I say the following:
`^eval let vc = message.member.voiceChannel; vc.join();`
Theoretically, this is supposed to make my bot join whatever voice channel the user is in, but for some reason, it says FFMPEG is not found and throws some kind of Unhandled Promise error. As you can see, I installed ffmpeg and discord.js with node-opus + arbitrary ffmpeg. Is this an installation issue or is there a JavaScript command or something I need to run to fix this? I looked at two other SO questions relating to this problem, but their answer was based on Windows, not Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does entering `ffmpeg` in the terminal give you `command not found: ffmpeg` ?

If so, you need to add the ffmpeg directory to your $PATH. Enter this and add it to your ~/.bashrc file.

```
export PATH=$PATH:<path where you installed ffmpeg>
```

Comment: I'm dumb. I didn't know there was an ffmpeg command. Apparently I had to sudo apt install not npm install it. Now it's working perfectly! I'll go ahead and mark your answer as correct. I guess I just suck at googling things considering I did it for hours upon end.

Comment: I'm in the same situation as OP. I got this error as well. When I run ffmpeg in CMD, The directory is added to the $PATH. Can you help me with this?